# Dynamically adding @Output in Angular component?

Tags: angular

Working on an Angular component, there is a case where I need to add a lot of event emitters (.i.e `@Output`) variables.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    template: '<div>[SOMECODE]</div>',
    providers: [MyService],
})

export class MyComponent {
  @Input input1:any;
  @Output output1 = new EventEmitter<MyEventObject>();
}
```

Problem is I have a lot of variables like `output1` in a list (approx 200 events), how can I dynamically add those variables as `@Output` vars for the component?

Comment: Having 200 events in a component seems not like a good idea. I haven't tested something like that, but I'm pretty sure it will slow down the app massively

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `type` and differentiate between different types of event

Define `output1` with an object that includes type key and another object which will contain the actual data

```
@Output output1 = new EventEmitter<{ type: string, object: MyEventObject }>();

...

this.output1.emit({
    type: 'type-1',
    object: {
        someKey: 'test'
    }
})
```

While listening you can have a switch case or use if conditions:

```
this.output1.subscribe(data => {
    switch(data.type) {
        case 'type-1':
            // Do something
            break;
        case 'type-2':
            // Do something
            break;
    }
})
```

Having 200 events sounds like a lot, but if you still want to go ahead you can do it like this

Comment: It is a good possible way , but how users will subscribe to one particular event,
lets say we have two events
loaded and destroyed , how user will listen to just one event  (lets say only loaded)